# Order by error in create view in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create this view in SQL Server:

```
CREATE VIEW tblSanPham_VIEW 
AS 
    SELECT TenSP, MaDanhMuc, Mamau
    FROM tblSanPham 
    ORDER BY MaSP DESC
```

I'm getting this error:

> Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Procedure tblSanPham_VIEW, Line 6 [Batch Start Line 47]
>   The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: What exactly is your problem and what have you tried? Please try to provide an [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showing the code you currently have.

Comment: You cannot use an `ORDER BY` in the view definition - you can only specify `ORDER BY` when you **select** from a view .....

Comment: And the error is telling you the problem. When you reference the view, put in the `ORDER BY`: ` `SELECT * FROM dbo.YourView ORDER BY Your column;`

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server doesn't support `ORDER BY` inside a view. This happens to remove the possibility of a "double sort" where the view defines a sorting order then the application requests a different sort order when the view is accessed.

In fact, you can use it if you add `TOP`:

```
CREATE VIEW tblSanPham_VIEW
AS 
SELECT  TOP 100 PERCENT 
        TenSP,
        MaDanhMuc,
        Mamau
FROM    tblSanPham
ORDER BY MaSP DESC
```

In this case, the view gets created without an error but if you try to pull data from it `ORDER BY` is completely ignored.

Try using `ORDER BY` clause to the queries that pull data from your view, not to the code of the view itself.

Comment: *"but if you try to pull data from it ORDER BY is completely ignored"* - not according to my test (SQL server 2014)

Comment: @kobik, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql) specifically states "The ORDER BY clause does not guarantee ordered results when the view is queried, unless ORDER BY is also specified in the query itself". Although the results might be returned in the desired order, it is by happenstance depending on the execution plan. I would never rely on undocumented behavior.

Comment: @kobik you should only use ORDER BY when you select the view and not to the view's code. I think this is why the sorting is being ignored.

Comment: TELL ME WHY ADD TOP 100PER

Comment: In my opinion, `View` should not contain `Order by` clause.

Comment: @LêMinhPhượng i added TOP to show that you can add Order By, but as a i explained before you should not use it in your view's body because doesn't provide you with an accurate sorting.

Answer (score 0):

by adding a **TOP** clause

```
CREATE VIEW tblSanPham_VIEW 
AS

SELECT TOP (99.9999) PERCENT     TenSP,
       MaDanhMuc,
       Mamau
FROM   tblSanPham
ORDER BY
       MaSP                DESC
```

OR if you just select from the view, without an **ORDER BY** clause:

```
CREATE VIEW tblSanPham_VIEW 
AS

SELECT TenSP,
       MaDanhMuc,
       Mamau
FROM   tblSanPham
```

Then:

```
SELECT *
FROM   dbo.tblSanPham_VIEW
ORDER BY
       MaSP DESC
```

Comment: i do the first way CREATE VIEW tblSanPham_VIEW 
AS

SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT     TenSP,
       MaDanhMuc,
       Mamau
FROM   tblSanPham
ORDER BY
       MaSP                DESC
 , and I create successfully a table, but when execute select * from tblSanPham_View that is not following DESC

Comment: Nope - the addition of the top directive only overcomes the error in creating the view. A query that references a view returns a resultset that has no defined order if that statement does not have an order by clause - just like it does when referencing a table. And the engine is smarter - it ignores "top 100 percent" in such cases since it is pointless.

Comment: @Lê Minh Phượng and @SMor thanks.  i change `SELECT TOP (100) ` to `SELECT TOP (99.9999) ` i think so this is correct now

Comment: oh I only execute /*
CREATE VIEW tblSP_VIEW 
AS
SELECT MaSP, TenSP, MaDanhMuc, Mamau 
FROM tblSanPham

 SELECT * FROM  tblSP_VIEW ORDER BY MaSP DESC */